# HTML website reloading when browser size change

Tags: javascript, html, css, reload

**hello, my HTML website restarting when browser size changes. please help me to fix this.**

This is the website http://hampton.settech.info/

**i uploaded my files to here** Here is the code files

https://mega.nz/folder/7pRmAQaJ#HzgQkG5N7xJ4wVIPSM3B6g

Answer (score 4):

Your page isn't actually reloading when the browser window size changes.

Instead, your site's layout is reset and its animations are restarted because there's a function called `resize()` in your `main.js` file which does the reset, and it's wired-up to jQuery's window resize event (at the top of `main.js`).

Remove the `resize()` function or rewrite it so it doesn't restart all animations from scratch.

Here is the offending code:

```
/**
 * Add All the Custom JS Here
 */

var pscroll;
var w,h,t1,t2,t3,t4;
$(window).on('load', animatee);
$(window).on('resize', resize);
  
  function resize(){

    clearTimeout(t1);
    clearTimeout(t2);
    clearTimeout(t3);
    clearTimeout(t4);

        $('.overlay').removeClass('overlayHidden');
        $('.logo2').addClass('animatee');
        $('.footer__content,.copy').css('display','none');
        $('.logo2').css({
         top: 'auto',
         left: 'auto',
         width: w - (w*0.5)+'px',
         height: h - (h*0.5)+'px'
        });
        $('.main-nav.no-anim').removeClass('aanim');
        $('.footer__title').removeClass('aanim0');
        $('.main-content__right-sidebar.no-anim').removeClass('aanim2');
        //$('.main-content__wrap > div').removeClass('aanim3');
        $('.main-content__left-sidebar-title,.main-nav ul,.social-icons,.footer__title > div').removeClass('anim4');
        $('.main-content__details').removeClass('main-content__details__scroll');
        $('.main-content__title,.main-content__left-sidebar-wrap').removeClass('anim4');
        $('.content-area > div').hide();
        $('.nav-links li').removeClass('cactive');

        animatee();
  }
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply.i added this code on main.js.but it's not working